# UIPageViewControllerDelegate - willTransitionToViewControllers replacement for iOS 5

Tags: ios, delegates, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers
```

to track current visible page in a `UIPageViewController`. This method is available from iOS 6 but I need to achieve this also in iOS 5 , how could I do that?
I tried with

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
```

but `previousViewControllers` count is always one, so it's no help or probably I'm missing something

Comment: What is the spine location of your `pageViewController`?

Comment: `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin`, that why `previousViewControllers` is one, I see

Comment: Yup, so it will show one view controller on screen at a time and you will get a reference to the view controller going out of screen in that array.

Comment: Any idea for getting the actual page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIPageViewController` can show two `UIViewController` instances when it has its spine location at `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid`,otherwise it shows one.

To get a reference to the view controller currently going out of the view, you can have it via the `previousViewControllers` parameter in its delegate. It will contain the references to the view controllers previously being shown on screen.

For eg. if you have MyContentViewController class which is being passed in your page view controller's datasource methods, you can get the reference to the view controller which is going out of screen in the delegate as:

```
MyContentViewController *myVC = (MyContentViewController*)[previousViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

And to get the reference to current view controller, use `viewControllers` property of `UIPageViewController`.

```
MyContentViewController *myVC = (MyContentViewController*)[[self.pageViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```